# IE7 cutting bottom of letters

Tags: css, internet-explorer-7

Almost all of my text in page look like this in IE7

[image]

Structure:

```
<div>
  <span>Andrea</span>
</div>
<div>
  <span>Puglisi</span>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div {

    font-size: 35px;
    height: 35px;
    line-height: 35px;
    padding-top: 5px;
}
```

I try increase height etc, nothing works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Increase your line-height (along with height) until the problem goes away or remove line-height (and height) altogether and let the browser set the default line-height for your specified font size (while the div expands with content).

```
div {
    font-size: 35px;
    height: 45px;
    line-height: 45px;
    padding-top: 5px;
}
```

or

```
div {
    font-size: 35px;
    padding-top: 5px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add some padding to bottom to fix problem.

```
padding-bottom:10px;
```